# Subclipse integration with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I did checkout from  SVN with tortoise SVN client in windows explorer and imported those projects under eclipse.

Now trying to integrate subclipse plugin with Eclipse(Kepler).Successfully installed the subclipse plugin from marketplace and restarted eclipse.
But i don't see the SVN options under Team in eclipse editor.

Do i need to have some settings in eclipse after subclipse installation(i was expecting subclipse will pick up the svn settings automatically
from tortoise svn), though settings suggested  under section "Set Subversion Preferences in Eclipse" at [link](https://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/subclipse-setup.html) are in place

Comment: Maybe you need a SVN Connector. What do you have when in Eclipse you go to Window > Preferences > Team > Svn > SVN Connector ?

Comment: There is no element of name SVN Connector  under SVN

Comment: @metaDiego Subclipse don't need connectors it has everything built-in and ready to use.

Comment: Are you right-clicking on a project already using Subversion? It does not appear in projects which haven't been checked out from a Subversion Repository. But you can use "Team -> Share Project..." and an option to publish it in SVN should appear.

Comment: I would add your repo's to your SVN repo list available in eclipse via Subclipse. Check out the projects into your workspace through the repo browser in eclipse. I experience difficulties while mixing tortise and subclipse usage, so try to stick with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the order in which you did things, you have to "connect" the project to SVN.  Right-click and choose Team > Share Project.  Then follow the wizard to select SVN. It should recognize it is an existing checkout and just "connect" it to Subclipse.  After that, the Team options will show up.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But when i di Team >Share Project >SVN i get the below error org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs to be upgraded
svn: The working copy at 'C:\...'
is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.10 (r1615264)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

Comment: I came across this thread but i am already using subclipse client version 1.10

Comment: Upgrade TortoiseSVN to SVN 1.8 and then use its option to upgrade the working copy.  That will be easiest solution.

Comment: Mark. I am not sure how tortoise SVN coming into picture here and need of upgrading to 1.8 as mytortoise SVN client is working fine under windows explorer. But i am facing issue when i do Team >Share Project >SVN in eclipse kepler(subclipse installed). Is n't a issue with subclipse ?

Comment: TortoiseSVN enters the picture because you put it there.  You checked out your code using TortoiseSVN 1.7.x.  That means the SVN working copy format is for SVN 1.7.  A SVN 1.8 client cannot use this working copy without upgrading it.  Once it does, a 1.7 client will not be able to use it.  So you should upgrade TortoiseSVN to 1.8 so that all of your SVN clients are the same SVN version.

Comment: Ok now getting you. You mean to say that boyh Tortoise SVN and subclipse should belong to same version either 1.7.x or 1.8.x.Right? I am facing issue becoz Tortoise SVN is 1.7 but subclipse is 1.8. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use multiple SVN clients on the same working copy then they MUST all be from the same SVN major.minor version family. SVN 1.8.x is 18 months old now and the best available version. Also any 1.x client can talk to any 1.y server so there is rarely a good reason not to run the very latest client version.